# Unable to display background image using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

The problem is when I run this code, the buttons, the labels, are showed up. But only the background image doesn't. I do not know what happen to it. I tried to refer to solution available on the internet, but did not find solution. Anyway, this code can be run without error. Please help me.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np




class ProcessImage_window:
    def __init__(self, master):  # parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)

        # Define images and icons
        self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:\\xampp\htdocs\PyFYP\images\\neon.png'))


        # OpenCV window name
        self.windowName = "Selected Image"

        # Background image
        self.Img_process_background = Label(master, image=self.bg)
        self.Img_process_background.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        # Attributes for setting coordinates
        self.coordinate = np.zeros((3, 2), int)
        self.counter = 0
        self.file_path_name = ""  # Uploaded image's file path

        # Labels and Buttons

        # Upload Image label and entry
        self.uploadImg_label = Label(master, text="Please upload your preference image here.", bg="#1f1a30",
                                     font=("arial", 12, "bold"), fg="white")
        self.uploadImg_label.place(x=50, y=50)
        self.uploadImg_note = Label(master, text="* Only jpg, jpeg, png, are allowed.", bg="#1f1a30",
                                    font=("arial", 8, "bold"), fg="grey")
        self.uploadImg_note.place(x=50, y=75)
        self.img_resize_note = Label(master, text="* Image will be resize to 900x500.", bg="#1f1a30",
                                     font=("arial", 8, "bold"), fg="grey")
        self.img_resize_note.place(x=50, y=100)
        self.txt_uploadImg = Entry(master, font=("arial", 10), bg="#39304d", fg="white", borderwidth=0)
        self.txt_uploadImg.place(x=50, y=125, width=350, height=20)


def main_image_process():
    imageprocess_page = tk.Tk()
    imageprocess_page.title("Image processing")

    imageprocess_page.iconbitmap('C:\\xampp\htdocs\PyFYP\Icon\snake2.ico')
    imageprocess_page.resizable(False, False)

    app_width = 900
    app_height = 500

    screen_width = imageprocess_page.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = imageprocess_page.winfo_screenheight()

    sys_width = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
    sys_height = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)
    imageprocess_page.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(sys_width)}+{int(sys_height)}')
    ProcessImage_window(imageprocess_page)
    imageprocess_page.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_image_process()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you don't have a reference to the instance of `ProcessImage_window()` so items without external reference, like `self.bg`, will be garbage collected.

Save a reference of `ProcessImage_window()`:

```py
def main_image_process():
    imageprocess_page = tk.Tk()
    imageprocess_page.title("Image processing")

    imageprocess_page.iconbitmap('C:\\xampp\htdocs\PyFYP\Icon\snake2.ico')
    imageprocess_page.resizable(False, False)

    app_width = 900
    app_height = 500

    screen_width = imageprocess_page.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = imageprocess_page.winfo_screenheight()

    sys_width = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
    sys_height = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)
    imageprocess_page.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(sys_width)}+{int(sys_height)}')
    app = ProcessImage_window(imageprocess_page) # save a reference
    imageprocess_page.mainloop()
```